# HTML grid system where elements with different heights will automatically take up avaliable space

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, grid-layout

How would we prevent the excess space, say between A and D.
http://jsfiddle.net/samarthwiz/4KCSx/

```
<div>A</div>
<div style="height: 170px">LONGER</div>
<div>C</div>
<div>D</div>
<div style="height: 100px">SHORTER</div>
<div>E</div>
<div>F</div>
<div>G</div>
<div>H</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is possible with CSS alone. However, there are several tools that use JavaScript to dynamically organize blocks for optimal use of space. The one I'm most familiar with is Masonry: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this,see the below link
 www.jsfiddle.net/4KCSx/1/